# What is the fastest way to know the points inside the polygon in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, polygon, points

I like to know what is the fastest way to know the points inside the polygon. Before I used the following code, but it is so slow. I have no ideas about search engines in python but if any one know something about it, I would appreciate him to make me aware too.

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
poly = Polygon(num)
with open(file , w) as f:
    if poly.contains(points) is True:
        f.write(points)
```

Comment: Is `Polygon` a standard library? Can you give a reference?

Comment: I edited the main code for the reference.